# ChromeのDeveloperツールで編集したStyleを一括コピーする方法

Tags: css, google-chrome

スタイルシートを編集するときに添付した画像のようにChromeのDeveloperツールでスタイルシートを編集して、その値をメモしておいて`style.css`などに記述するという方法をとっているのですが、この値を一括してコピーする方法はありますか？

[image: スタイルシート編集中]

今回の場合ですと

```
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
  margin: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: inherit;
  color: #888;
}
```

を一括コピーできれば嬉しいのですが。

Comment: 単純に表示されている欲しい範囲をドラッグして範囲選択し右クリック(あるいはctrl+C)からコピーできると思いますが。

Comment: チェックを外しても既存の回答にあるようにコメントアウトされるだけなので`inherit`にはなりませんよ？(条件の重複するプロパティで試すと分かりやすいですね)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 単純にコピーできる事に気づいていませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @hinaloe そうですね、すいません質問が正確ではありませんでした。同一要素を別スタイルシートで上書きする時に使えるコードを意識していました。ただ、そうなると妙な動作になってしまうのでなさそうですね。

Comment: 回答した後に思ったのですが、値を`inherit`に書き換えて単純にコピーすれば良さそうですね。(チェックを外さずに)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Elements`の`Style`タブで変更された内容は、一時的にcssファイルに反映されています。

その為、スタイルの値を変更したり無効にした後、画像の`style.css:758`をクリックすれば下記の様なスタイルが表示されると思いますので、これをコピーすることはできます。

```css
.wp-caption .wp-caption-text {
    /* margin: 12px 12px 0 0; */
    font-size: 12px;
    /* font-style: italic; */
    color: #888;
}
```

※ ご期待されている一括コピーではありませんが...
※ cssがminifyされてる場合は1行で表示されます

Comment: 回答有難うございます。ただ、少し期待していた動作とは違うので質問はオープン状態で残させて頂きます。